# PowerShell .Save($path) changing formatting of xml file

Tags: xml, powershell, formatting

how to save the xml file modified by the script so that my formatting remains there?

Original pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>ArtifactParent</artifactId>
        <groupId>MaxGroup</groupId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </parent>

   <artifactId>Artefact</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>pom</packaging>
   <name>This is my name</name>

   <modules>
       <module>Module1</module>
       <module>Module2</module>
   </modules>

   <dependencyManagement>
       <dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>javax</groupId>
               <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
               <version>${javaee.version}</version>
               <scope>provided</scope>
           </dependency>
       </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

Purpose of script is change specific version of parent to new version.
PowerShell script :

```
$xmlDoc = [xml] Get-Content $xmlFileName

do-something

$xmlDoc.Save($file)
```

When I use this script, it delete all tabulators and new-lines.

New pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>ArtifactParent</artifactId>
    <groupId>MaxGroup</groupId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>Artefact</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>This is my name</name>
  <modules>
    <module>Module1</module>
    <module>Module2</module>
  </modules>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javaee.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Can you please advise me some solution which keep my formatting and also change version of parent.

Comment: It's a feature not a bug lol

Comment: @js2010 may be, but I need pom.xml look like original after updated version.

Comment: Why would you like to preserve the whitespaces? Are you having issues with, say, file comparison?

Comment: @vonPryz No, simpler solution, company policy. I need to preserve original formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent .Net's XML library about re-formatting the file, one needs to first tell XML Document not to mess with whitespace. This is done via creating a XmlDocument object, setting [PreserveWhitespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.preservewhitespace?view=net-6.0) as true and then loading the document content into it. Like so,

```
$xmlDoc = new-object xml.xmldocument                             
$xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = $true                               
$xmlDoc.Load($xmlFileName)
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but when I replace this my line of conde `$xmlDoc = [xml](Get-Content $xmlFileName)` with your advice (exept 'pom.xml' using $xmlFileName), result is the same like New pom.xml exemple. Script formatted my formatting.

Comment: Did you also set the `.PreserveWhitespace` attribute before loading the content?

Comment: I found where was a problem, your solution helped me a lot, but it wasnt working until I change your `$xmlDoc.Load('pom.xml')` to mine `$xmlDoc.Load($file)`, problem was in path of loading file, I dont know why with 'pom.xml' dont working but with full path in Load is workig all fine. If you want, you can edit your post and then I will mark him as solution to my problem @vonPryz